# For a given chess board where k queens are already placed, find the solution to the N queen problem

Tags: c#, algorithm

This is the classic 8 queen problem but in this case, a N x N board is given whereby a certain number of queens are already placed. You are required to fill the remainder of the board.

Sample input:

```
.Q..
...Q
....
....
```

Expected output

```
.Q..
...Q
Q...
..Q.
```

The code below is based on backtracking and works only if the board is empty ie doesn't have any queens placed on it. How can I modify it such that it places queens that have not been placed such that they do not attack each other

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace CSharp_Shell
{

    public static class Program 
    {

        static void printBoard(string [, ] board) {  
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {  
                for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {  
                    Console.Write(board[i, j] + " ");  
                }  
                Console.Write("\n");  
            }  
        }  

        static bool isSafe(string [,] board, int row, int col)
        {
            int i, j;
           for (i = 0; i < col; i++) 
               if (board[row, i] == "Q") 
                   return false; 


            /* Check upper diagonal on left side */
            for (i=row, j=col; i>=0 && j>=0; i--, j--) 
                if (board[i, j]  == "Q") 
                    return false; 

            /* Check lower diagonal on left side */
            for (i=row, j=col; j>=0 && i<4; i++, j--) 
                if (board[i, j] == "Q") 
                    return false;
                return true;
        }
            static bool solve8queen(string[,] board, int col)
            {
                //base case
                if(col >= 4)
                   return true;

                //loop over rows
                for(int row = 0; row < 4; row++)
                {
                    //check if queen can be placed
                    if(isSafe(board, row, col))
                    {
                        //place the queen
                        board[row, col] = "Q";


                        //explore next solution
                        if(solve8queen(board, col + 1))
                           return true;

                        //Backtrack
                        board[row, col] = ".";

                    }


                }

                return false;

            }

        public static void Main()
        {
            string [,] board = {

                           {".", "Q", ".", "."},
                           {".", ".", ".", "Q"},
                           {".", ".", ".", "."},
                           {".", ".", ".", "."}

                         };

            solve8queen(board, 0);
            printBoard(board);

        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Hint: Use `q` instead of `Q` as your queen. In the `isSafe` consider `q` & `Q` both as queens.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can skip the columns that already occupies a Queen. You also need to modify isSafe() function to look at the whole view, instead of just back placed ones.

As such:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace CSharp_Shell
{

    public static class Program
    {

        static void printBoard(string [, ] board) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                    Console.Write(board[i, j] + " ");
                }
                Console.Write("\n");
            }
        }

        static bool isSafe(string [,] board, int row, int col)
        {
            int i, j;
           /* Check this row completely */
            for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
                if (board[row, i] == "Q")
                    return false;

            /* Check upper diagonal on left side */
            for (i=row, j=col; i>=0 && j>=0; i--, j--)
                if (board[i, j] == "Q")
                    return false;

            /* Check bottom diagonal on right side */
            for (i=row, j=col; i<4 && j<4; i++, j++)
                if (board[i, j] == "Q")
                    return false;

            /* Check lower diagonal on left side */
            for (i=row, j=col; j>=0 && i<4; i++, j--)
                if (board[i, j] == "Q")
                    return false;

            /* Check upper diagonal on right side */
            for (i=row, j=col; j<4 && i>=0; i--, j++)
                if (board[i, j] == "Q")
                    return false;

                return true;
        }
            static bool solve8queen(string[,] board, int col)
            {
                //base case
                if(col >= 4) {
                    printBoard(board);
                    return true;
                }

                bool res = false;
                //loop over rows
                for(int row = 0; row < 4; row++)
                {
                    //check if queen can be placed
                    if(isSafe(board, row, col))
                    {
                        //place the queen
                        board[row, col] = "Q";



                        // Skip evaluating column 1
                        if(col + 1 == 1)
                            col++;

                        // Skip evaluating column 3
                        if(col + 1 == 3)
                            col++;

                        //explore next solution
                        res = solve8queen(board, col + 1) || res;

                        //Backtrack
                        board[row, col] = ".";

                    }


                }

                return false;

            }

        public static void Main()
        {
            string [,] board = {

                           {".", "Q", ".", "."},
                           {".", ".", ".", "Q"},
                           {".", ".", ".", "."},
                           {".", ".", ".", "."}

                         };

            solve8queen(board, 0);
            //printBoard(board);

        }


    }
}
```

This will result in the following output:

```
. Q . .
. . . Q
Q . . .
. . Q .
```

Another possible way would be to modify the N queen problem to print out all possible moves. And select the appropriate output from the list. If none match, then solution does not exist.